# Is this really a bad question? (Failed audit)

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I was reviewing the reopen queue, and I got this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21256148

[image]

I think it is a perfectly valid question. Sure, it could have been good with a bit of research, but I don't think it is very unclear. And even if the question should be closed, I certainly don't think it's bad enough to be used as an audit.

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically. This was chosen as a _"known bad"_ because of the all the down-votes with no up-votes, and by having not haivng any "reopen" votes in its history. I have no clue if the question is any good or not, but if you think it shouldn't be closed just vote to reopen outside of the queue, and possibly up-vote the question if you think it is good and useful.

Comment: I'm guessing that it was closed as 'Too broad' - the catch-all for when an OP  needs a 'C++ 101' course with personal tuition.

Comment: @MartinJames: It was closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is closed because it's unclear what they are asking (or at least what they are asking does not make any sense at all).

The code example op uses:

```
int* ptr_a = 1;
```

is not legal c++ and does not compile on any compiler I'd know. Visual studio error says:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'

GCC throws a similar error.

It is unclear how/why op thinks that the two code segments are similar. The only reason I could imagine is that they never tested the second one.

I can't say anything about the value of this question as a review audit, but it should definitely stay closed.

Comment: It requires some C++ knowledge to review this question correctly...?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, definitely. A lot of questions in the close-vote queue and in the reopen queue do. That's why you can filter by tags.

Comment: And that is what the skip button is for. When in doubt, skip.

Comment: @user202729 most questions in the close queue require some amount of domain knowledge to review correctly.